# Illegal characters in path c# error

Tags: c#

I am getting the error

> Illegal characters in path

for the code below . Please help me out.

```
response.Clear();
response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;

// set the response mime type for excel
response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
string sFileName = "Testeeeeee.xls";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + sFileName + "\"");

// create a string writer
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
    using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
    {
        // instantiate a datagrid
        DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
        dg.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
        dg.DataBind();
        dg.RenderControl(htw);
        string sPath = @"E:\CR-12\Test.xls";
        File.WriteAllText(sw.ToString(), sPath);// I get the error at this line
        response.End();
```

Comment: The error I am getting is  "Illegal characters in path"

Answer (score 14):

The [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) are inverted. Do it as follows:

```
File.WriteAllText(sPath,sw.ToString());
```

Answer (score 5):

You've got the parameters to `File.WriteAllText` mixed up. The first one is the path, the second is the contents. You need

```
File.WriteAllText(sPath, sw.ToString());
```

Answer (score 4):

The call to

```
File.WriteAllText(sw.ToString(), sPath);
```

has the wrong parameter order. It should be

```
File.WriteAllText(sPath, sw.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

For others receiving this error, make sure you are using backslashes correctly since they are also escape characters. A single backslash can result in this error. Use 2 backslashes to properly output a single escaped backslash.

Ex:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\file.txt", output);
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is probably a security related one. Your webpage wouldn't be default have access to the E drive.